# how to calculate the revenue made by a cohort in every month from the five months after subscription date?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in the following query i'm trying to extract a group of users ( cohort )  caracterized by : [date of subscription + pays + operateur + sspdt] , for every cohort i need to calculate the number of subscribers and the revenue those users are generating during each operation month , we should have 6 operation months ( 6 months after subscription date data ) , we need to create a new column named index which will contain values from 0 to 5 which refers to the difference in month between operation month and subscription month ( index = 0 --> operattion month = subscription month , index = 1 --> operation month = subscription month + 1 month )
note that :
id  is the subscriber id and it exists in two tables A and B , revers is the revenue generated by an id in a date named date rebill in table B too , date abo is date of subscription )
i tried this query but its not giving the result i want :

```
SELECT
  s.subscription_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) AS subscriber_count,
  SUM(f.revers) AS monthly_revenue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) / NULLIF(SUM(f.revers), 0) AS arpu_local
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', a.dateabo::date) AS subscription_month,
      o.pays,
      o.operateurname,
      a.sspdt,
      a.id
    FROM
      table A as  a
    
    WHERE
      o.pays = 'US'
      AND a.dateabo::date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2023-04-01'
    GROUP BY
      subscription_month,
      o.pays,
      o.operateurname,
      a.sspdt,
      a.id
  ) AS s
LEFT JOIN
  table B as r ON s.id = r.id
  AND DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_TIMESTAMP(r.DATE_REBILL)) = s.subscription_month

GROUP BY
  s.subscription_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt,
 
ORDER BY
  s.subscription_month DESC;
```

i think i'm having a problem in this line :
AND DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_TIMESTAMP(r.DATE_REBILL)) = s.subscription_month

since here i'm getting the output correct but only if index = 0 ( index column dosent exist and i need to create it too )

Comment: This is a very muddled question, to begin with you have an alias `f` for a non-existent table, and yet you note these values come from `table b`. Your base problem appears to be about `how do I cross join a fixed set of values` and then. There is a how to a get the answers I want. All the while show chunks of SQL that don't really matter to the question. Oh yes, `delay = 0` given this is not mentioned anywhere else, how does it relate?

Answer (score 0):

it might be simple if the sub-select used a `DISINCT` instead of `GROUP BY x,y,z`, as the have the same impact:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
      DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', a.dateabo::date) AS subscription_month,
      o.pays,
      o.operateurname,
      a.sspdt,
      a.id
    FROM table_A as a  
    WHERE o.pays = 'US'
      AND a.dateabo::date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2023-04-01'
```

but really from this question perspective, this section could be simplified to I have some results that look like...

so that sub-select could then just be some values like:

```
WITH sub_select(subscription_month, pays, operateurname, sspdt, id) as (
    select * from values 
        ('2023-04-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 100),
        ('2023-03-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 101)
)
```

now we need some fake values for `table_b`:

```
table_b(id, revers, DATE_REBILL) as (
    select * from values 
        (100, 123.01, '2023-04-11'),
        (101, 111.02, '2023-03-12'),
        (101, 111.02, '2023-04-12')
)
```

which ran though your sql:

```
SELECT
  s.subscription_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) AS subscriber_count,
  SUM(r.revers) AS monthly_revenue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) / NULLIF(SUM(r.revers), 0) AS arpu_local
FROM sub_select AS s
LEFT JOIN table_B as r 
    ON s.id = r.id
      AND DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_TIMESTAMP(r.DATE_REBILL)) = s.subscription_month
GROUP BY
  s.subscription_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt
ORDER BY
  s.subscription_month DESC;
```

gives:

| SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH | PAYS | OPERATEURNAME | SSPDT | SUBSCRIBER_COUNT | MONTHLY_REVENUE | ARPU_LOCAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 1 | 123.01 | 0.008129 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 1 | 111.02 | 0.009007 |

which makes sense from a "what this SQL does" but it's not the "what you want"

So what I think you expect to see would be:

| SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH | PAYS | OPERATEURNAME | SSPDT | SUBSCRIBER_COUNT | MONTHLY_REVENUE | ARPU_LOCAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 2 | 234.03 | 0.008129 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 1 | 111.02 | 0.009007 |

because they span more time.

So assuming `table_a` is the subscription data, this is the table to want to do a cross join with:

```
WITH sub_select(subscription_month, pays, operateurname, sspdt, id) as (
    select * from values 
        ('2023-04-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 100),
        ('2023-03-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 101)
)
    select a.*, b.*
    from sub_select as a
    cross join (select column1 as index from values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) as b
;
```

gives:

| SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH | PAYS | OPERATEURNAME | SSPDT | ID | INDEX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 0 |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 1 |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 2 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 2 |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 3 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 3 |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 4 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 4 |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 5 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 5 |

Now to join the operational data to the revue, you want to use an altered month, which I would put into the CTE that builds this value.

So this might look like:

```
WITH sub_select(subscription_month, pays, operateurname, sspdt, id) as (
    select * from values 
        ('2023-04-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 100),
        ('2023-03-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 101)
), table_b(id, revers, date_rebill) as (
    select * from values 
        (100, 123.01, '2023-04-11'),
        (101, 111.02, '2023-03-12'),
        (101, 111.02, '2023-04-12')
), opperational_months as (
    select 
        a.*, 
        c.*, 
        dateadd('month', c.index, TO_TIMESTAMP(a.subscription_month)) as opp_month
    from sub_select as a
    cross join (
        select column1 as index from values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
    ) as c
), clean_table_b as (
    select 
        b.*,
        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_TIMESTAMP(b.date_rebill)) as clean_month
    from table_b as b
)
select s.*, r.*
FROM opperational_months AS s
LEFT JOIN clean_table_b as r 
    ON s.id = r.id
      AND r.clean_month = s.opp_month
order by 1 desc;
```

which gives:

| SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH | PAYS | OPERATEURNAME | SSPDT | ID | INDEX | OPP_MONTH | ID_2 | REVERS | DATE_REBILL | CLEAN_MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 0 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 123.01 | 2023-04-11 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 1 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 2 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 3 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 4 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 100 | 5 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 0 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 101 | 111.02 | 2023-03-12 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 1 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 101 | 111.02 | 2023-04-12 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 2 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 3 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 4 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 101 | 5 | 2023-08-01 00:00:00.000 | null | null | null | null |

Which joins all how I would expect it, but it does mean, that the code you had to summarize on "subscription month" would give unexpected results:

| SUBSCRIPTION_MONTH | PAYS | OPERATEURNAME | SSPDT | SUBSCRIBER_COUNT | MONTHLY_REVENUE | ARPU_LOCAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | US | AA | 1 | 1 | 123.01 | 0.008129 |
| 2023-03-01 | US | AA | 1 | 1 | 222.04 | 0.004504 |

because as the prior table shows, the two operational months of id 101, have the same subscription.

so change sub_month for opp_month, like so:

```
SELECT
  s.opp_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) AS subscriber_count,
  SUM(r.revers) AS monthly_revenue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) / NULLIF(SUM(r.revers), 0) AS arpu_local
FROM opperational_months AS s
LEFT JOIN clean_table_b as r 
    ON s.id = r.id
      AND r.clean_month = s.opp_month
GROUP BY
  s.opp_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt
ORDER BY
  s.opp_month DESC;
```

gives equally fun results, as the values for the count are the left side time exploded value:

| OPP_MONTH | PAYS | OPERATEURNAME | SSPDT | SUBSCRIBER_COUNT | MONTHLY_REVENUE | ARPU_LOCAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 2023-07-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 2 | 234.03 | 0.008546 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 1 | 111.02 | 0.009007 |

this can be fixed by swapping to use the `count( distinct r.id)`

```
  COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) AS subscriber_count,
  SUM(r.revers) AS monthly_revenue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) / NULLIF(SUM(r.revers), 0) AS arpu_local
```

OR you could leave it how you had it, and do the 0-5 value windows expansion on the revenue (`table_b`) rows instead of the customer rows. And this would work also, BUT I assume you have more months of revenue than you have subscriptions, so it is better to expand the smaller table, than the bigger table.

So the final SQL for this example is:

```
WITH sub_select(subscription_month, pays, operateurname, sspdt, id) as (
    select * from values 
        ('2023-04-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 100),
        ('2023-03-01', 'US', 'AA', 1, 101)
), table_b(id, revers, date_rebill) as (
    select * from values 
        (100, 123.01, '2023-04-11'),
        (101, 111.02, '2023-03-12'),
        (101, 111.02, '2023-04-12')
), opperational_months as (
    select 
        a.*, 
        c.*, 
        dateadd('month', c.index, TO_TIMESTAMP(a.subscription_month)) as opp_month
    from sub_select as a
    cross join (
        select column1 as index from values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
    ) as c
), clean_table_b as (
    select 
        b.*,
        DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', TO_TIMESTAMP(b.date_rebill)) as clean_month
    from table_b as b
)
SELECT
  s.opp_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) AS subscriber_count,
  SUM(r.revers) AS monthly_revenue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) / NULLIF(SUM(r.revers), 0) AS arpu_local
FROM opperational_months AS s
LEFT JOIN clean_table_b as r 
    ON s.id = r.id
      AND r.clean_month = s.opp_month
GROUP BY
  s.opp_month,
  s.pays,
  s.operateurname,
  s.sspdt
ORDER BY
  s.opp_month DESC;
```

gives:

| OPP_MONTH | PAYS | OPERATEURNAME | SSPDT | SUBSCRIBER_COUNT | MONTHLY_REVENUE | ARPU_LOCAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 2023-08-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 2023-07-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 2023-06-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 0 |  |  |
| 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 2 | 234.03 | 0.008546 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00.000 | US | AA | 1 | 1 | 111.02 | 0.009007 |

And if you don't want the zero rows, you can filter out at the end with a HAVING or you could change the LEFT JOIN into a JOIN, and have none of this mess. the way you, might be dictated by things you have chopped out, in making this an example/sharable question.